# Odoo 8 - Mass Edit and Field Domains

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a model in a custom plugin that I'm developing with a field that I want to restrict to a particular domain. My model looks something like:

```python
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class MyModel(osv.Model):
    _name = 'mymodel'
    _columns = {
        'ui_code_version': fields.many2one(
            comodel_name='robots.software.versions', 
            string='UI Code Version', 
            domain="[('project', '=', 'ui')]"
        )
    }
```

When directly editing an instance of my model, it seems like the `domain` *is* properly restricting my choices to **ui** project versions, which is great.

However, if I set up the [Mass Editing](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/mass_editing/) module so that I can edit the **ui** versions of multiple instances of `mymodel`, the domain filter is *not* applied and I can erroneously select software versions from other projects.

Poking around in the database, it looks like the domain isn't even being stored there.

```
MyOdooDatabase> SELECT name, domain FROM ir_model_fields \
                WHERE model = 'mymodel' AND name = 'ui_code_version'
+-----------------------+----------+
| name                  |   domain |
|-----------------------+----------|
| ui_code_version       |   <null> |
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Similarly, the domain isn't in the Settings->Technical->Database Structure->Fields entry for this field:

[image: Screenshot of Field Settings]

**Q**: How can I get the Mass Editing module to obey my fields domain so that I can only select ui project versions?  Does that domain need to be stored in the database? If so, how?

---

Edit: As requested by [Bhavesh Odedra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2926754/bhavesh-odedra), below are the definitions for `robots.software.versions` and `robots.software.projects`:

```python
class RobotsSoftwareVersions(osv.Model):
    _name = 'robots.software.versions'
    _description = 'Software Version'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name'),
        'project': fields.many2one('robots.software.projects', 'Project'),
        'version': fields.char('Version', help='The git tag or hash (e.g. 3.2.1)')
    }

class RobotsSoftwareProjects(osv.Model):
    _name = 'robots.software.projects'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name'),
        'upstream': fields.char('Upstream'),
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us `robots.software.versions` table where you have declared `project` field ?

Comment: @BhaveshOdedra Done, see above

Answer (score 0):

Domain should be

```
domain="[('project', '=', 'ui')]"
```

**Updated**

- Add `project_name` field in `robots.software.versions` object and make it related with `project` like

  `'project_name': fields.related('project', 'name', type='char', store=True)`
- Now update your domain like

  `domain=[('project_name', '=', 'ui')]`

Comment: I had a typo in my stackoverflow post. The domain was correctly defined already in my actual code. See above for the edit. Nice catch though!

Comment: `project` field is declared `many2one` so It will store integer ID in database. U will enter project name as `ui` correct ?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.  I wasn't actually sure if the `domain` specification would work, but it does when I'm editing a single field (see here: https://imgur.com/a/MPFatg9).

Comment: I modified the `robots.software.versions` to include the `project_name` field and updated the domain accordingly.  The result is the same: software versions are filtered when editing a single robot, but are not filtered when using the Mass Edit module.  Also, the domain is not listed in the entry in the `ir_model_fields` database table.